# Android Accessibility feature is not working with single touch but it is working with swipe gesture

Tags: android

I have an edit text and two buttons in my layout. I set content descriptions for those three. When accessibility is enabled in the device i touched on the edit text. focus is not shifted  to the edit text and content description is not heard. If i navigate to the edit text by swiping. Hint will be heard. same case happened with the buttons also.

If anyone faced the same problem and got the solution plz explain me why it behaves like that.
Thanks in advance.

Here i am sharing my xml part related to those views

```
   <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchfield"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/searchfield_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dialpad_searchfield_height"
            android:background="@drawable/search_field_statelist"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/syn_ic_search_bar_magnify"
            android:drawablePadding="12dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions|textEmailAddress"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/dialpad_searchfield_text_padding_right"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:hint="@string/search_field_hint"
            android:contentDescription="@string/search_field_hint"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />


    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/call"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dialpad_button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dialpad_searchfield_height"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/syn_btn_action"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/syn_ic_offhook_ab"
            android:contentDescription="@string/call" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/speeddial"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dialpad_button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dialpad_searchfield_height"
            android:background="@drawable/dial_keypad"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/syn_btn_default_normal"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_regular"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:contentDescription="@string/speeddial"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            />
```